# TypeScript doesn't throw errors on later initialized ANY variable

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function which only accepts a number variable.

```
function add(n1: number) {
    return n1 + n1;
}
```

And I initialize an any variable and assign it a string of '5'

```
let number1;
number1 = '5';
```

I was wondering, why doesn't it show an error when I want to pass a string to the function?

`console.log(add(number1));`

(Of course it outputs 55, because the string is concatenated.)

Comment: [I'm getting the expected error.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoBRgIwC5FggC2ARgKYBOAlIgN4BQiTiFZUIFSOiA1AdgG56AX3r0ANmwLFyFQfUKlK2RAF5EAcgCsGofQgIAznEkA6cXADmGNJkWzsVKgKA)  Where specifically in the overall process are you checking for this error?  The resulting JavaScript is still JavaScript and will still run without complaining about types.  It's only in the linting/transpiling that it will show an error.

Comment: @David That's weird. I'm running TS v4.3.5 and it doesn't show up on my IDE nor in the compiler: http://snpy.in/7hkYM1

Comment: I just learned something new from the answer below.  The website I was using had `noImplicitAny` selected.  Go into the config and de-select it and the behavior you describe is observed.

Comment: @David Just checked that and that was the problem. Thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the type is not specified (implicit `any`) or set to `any`, the uses of the variable won't be type-checked. This is useful if you gradually migrate JavaScript code to TypeScript.

If you want to flag implicit `any`'s (like the one in your example) as error, use the `noImplicitAny` compiler flag.

Comment: Yep. This is what I was looking for. I just followed along a tutorial and experimented on my own. Didn't get to the tsconfig file yet.